# SIM808 does not support SSL related AT commands

Tags: gsm, sim808

1. I am using a SIM808 module. It's working fine with normal MQTT over TCP, but does not work when trying secured MQTT.
2. I sent `AT+SSLSETROOT="C:\USER\HENRY_SSL.CRT"` to set the root certificate (see this document: "SIM800 Series_MQTT_Application Note_V1.03"). The response I'm getting from the GSM is: `+CME ERROR: unknown`.
3. When I try `AT+SMSSL=1`, I get the same error. I checked with HTTP commands and it's working fine, but the `AT+HTTPSSL=1` command does not work. The SIM808 does not respond to SSL related commands.

But as per the Simcom website, the SIM808 does support SSL. Do I need to upgrade any firmware?

Comment: could you send me that firmware version (1418B05SIM808M32)? or could you tell me the site that you download it?
Also, is there any newer firmware now?

Answer (score 1):

I updated the firmware version: 1418B05SIM808M32. Now all commands are working fine.

Comment: please send link of download firmware version: 1418B05SIM808M32